# What does the "aapl,panic-info" output from "nvram -p" mean?

Tags: firmware

When I run `nvram -p` I get the following:

```
$ nvram -p | cut -c1-30
aapl,panic-info %f0%b0;=F%8d%e
BootCampHD  %02%01%0c%00%d0A%03
boot-image  %02%01%0c%00%d0A%03
SystemAudioVolume   W
```

The line with `panic-info` is actually ~9000 characters long. What does this mean? Should I be worried, as the word 'panic' implies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `panic-info` is the details of the last kernel panic registered and stored by the system.  If you do a PRAM (or NVRAM) reset, those details will be removed.

For example, I just ran `nvram -p` and I had no `panic-info` line because I did a PRAM reset since my last kernel panic.  I can't even remember the last time I had a kernel panic.

Hope that clears it up for you.